# Plot the characteristic roots of complex equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, gnuplot

I want to draw the following pictures as plots in the  TikZ environment.
The first one is the characteristic roots of the  equation

```
\lambda + \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda}
```

and the second one is the characteristic roots of the equation

```
1 + 0.5 \mathrm{e}^{-0.5 \lambda}
```

[image: characteristic roots]

Comment: **4th** question: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228

Comment: `pgfplots` is the solution to you problem. You can provide a **MWE** with a specific question if it's not working after looking at related questions and the manual. Here are **many example**s: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

Comment: Honestly, I think that you are confusing LaTeX with a computer algebra system. You could compute the polylog with an external program and then use pgfplots for visualization, but if you expect pgfplots to know polylogs then I think you need to wait a few years. You could do it with contour plot using gnuplot, though.

Answer (score 2):

This code can be a starting point for you.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  ymin = -10,
  ymax = 30,
  xmin = -5,
  xmax = 2,
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  ]
    \addplot[samples at={-5,...,0}, only marks]{(x+e^(-x))};
    \addplot[samples at={-5,...,0}, only marks]{(1+0.5*e^(-0.5*x))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Mille grazie!!!